# What really is constant? Definition

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I'm getting a little confused about constant. It says here in Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ book that you cannot give a new value to constant.

```
constexpr int max = 17;
int val = 19;
max+2
```

but this code is confusing me. max+2, that means the max will have a new value, 19, so what really is constant? how come you can add 2 to a constant?

Comment: `max+2` doesn't modify `max`.

Comment: max+2 is an expression, and doesn't reassign max. Try reassign max, i.e. `max = max + 2` - the compiler will complain.

Comment: `3+2` doesn't mean `3` will have a new value, `5`.

Answer (score 3):

`max + 2` does not mean that `max` will have a new value. Any more than `17 + 2` means that 17 will have a new value. `max + 2` is an expression, the value of which is 19. After that expression is evaluated, `max` is still equal to 17.

Answer (score 1):

`max+2` is not modifying `max` in any way. It is merely an expression whose value is that of `max` plus `2`. Maybe you are confusing that with `max+=2` which you actually can't do. If you check the value of max after the last line of your code it will still be 17.

Comment: i understand now max+=2 is what i was thinking. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can use constants in expressions that produce a new value. In other words, `max + 2` consists of two constants (`max` and `2`) that are added together, to produce the value `19`. The `int val = 19;` is also using a true constant `19` (an integer literal, which is one form of constant in programming). `val` obviously ISN'T constant, it's valid to do `val += 9;` or `val = 32;` later on in the code. If you try to do `max = 7;` later on in your code, it won't compile [unless the compiler is broken]